# Unale to save runtime generated file to directory

Tags: php, file-upload

I have one form. When user submit the form, I will store the data on database and generate the pdf of the same. Here what I want to do is:

- Download PDF file;
- Save the PDF in a folder.

Downloading the PDF is working perfectly, but it is not being saved in a folder.

```
public function get_pdf() {
    $count = 1;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['description']); $i++) {
        $table_data[] = array(
            'serial' => $count,
            'description' => $_POST['description'][$i],
            'unit' => $_POST['unit'][$i],
            'quantity' => $_POST['quantity'][$i],
            'rate' => $_POST['rate'][$i],
            'amount' => $_POST['amount'][$i]
        );
        $count++;
    }

    if (!empty($table_data)) {
        // loading pdf library //
        $this->load->library('cezpdf');

        // field names //
        $table_data_field = array(
            'serial' => 'S.No.',
            'description' => 'Work Description',
            'unit' => 'Unit',
            'quantity' => 'Quantity',
            'rate' => 'Rate',
            'amount' => 'Amount'
        );

        $this->cezpdf->ezTable($table_data, $table_data_field, 'Quotation', array('width' => 500, 'justification' => 'center'));

        ob_start();
        $this->cezpdf->ezStream();
        $data = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        // save the quotation file on client folder //
        move_uploaded_file('Quotation', FCPATH . '/quotation/' . $data);

        // force to download the file //
        $this->load->helper('download');
        force_download('Quotation.pdf', $data);
    }
}
```

Please help me on this. I use CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't think you ought to be using `move_uploaded_file`, and secondly, the name of your file contains the contents of the PDF, not a filename.

Comment: then what is the solution david, i know     move_uploaded_file()   we are using while the file is uploaded through form. what can i use here? I don't get any idea or help over internet.

Comment: Problem solved, instead of
    
    `move_uploaded_file()`

I use

    `file_put_contents()`

Here it goes...
   
 `// save the quotation file on client folder //`
 
 `file_put_contents(FCPATH . 'quotation' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Quotation.pdf', $data);`

Thanks David.

Comment: Isn't `move_uploaded_file` designed for this?

Comment: @Tomalak: `move_uploaded_file` is for uploaded files, not files created inside an application.

Comment: @DavidGrant: That's what I get for not reading the whole question. :)